# EF: how to add 2 objects using the same NEW object in one transaction

Tags: entity-framework

My web application is using EF as ORM. The problem is that when I want to add House and Home object with the same address (Address object is also new in database), the error appears:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Houses_dbo.Houses_AddressId". 
The conflict occurred in database "devDB", table "dbo.Houses", column 'Id'.

Code doing inserts:

```
Address address = new Address(){Id=-1, AddressValue ="AAA"};
Home home = new Home(){Address = address }
Office office = new Office(){Address = address }

context.Offices.Add(office);
context.Homes.Add(home);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're manually setting the Address object's Id to -1? That seems very strange

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem because `Address` has the EntityState `Untracked`. A solution is to add the `Address` save, then add the saved instance to the other entities:

```
Address address = new Address(){ Id=-1, AddressValue ="AAA" };
context.Address.Add(address );
context.SaveChanges();

Home home = new Home(){Address = address }
Office office = new Office(){Address = address }

context.Offices.Add(office);
context.Homes.Add(home);
context.SaveChanges();
```

To prevent you from having an orphaned address if some further save-action failes, create a `Transaction`:

```
using(var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        //...
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean the trans object will rollback transaction made by SaveChanges command (transaction)? So is it  one transaction included in other transaction?

Comment: @P.K. Yes the transaction will rollback the transaction created in `SaveChanges`. Actually you have not to call `Rollback` because if you do not call `Commit` inside the `using` block the transaction will rollback at the time when the transaction is disposed.

Comment: solution looks good the question is if you tested this and you are sure it works?:) ... Im implementing this.

Comment: Yes it works, but as @Vlad274 says: why are you setting the ID of address? Shouldn't it be a IDENTITY column?

Comment: It's I think, its primary key INT field so it's auto increment by default?

Comment: If you set the value then `auto increment` is not used. If the DB has defined a IDENTITY on it, then you have not to set the value. It is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are specifying a negative Id to your address:

```
Address address = new Address(){Id=-1, AddressValue ="AAA"};
```

Primary Key ID can't be negative

If you are using Code-first then the ID should get generated automatically given that you have configured it to auto increment. Otherwise you need to calculate a positive unique ID.

Comment: So Id should be 0 instead of -1?